# Unable to map a network drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, shared-folders

I set my Music and Videos folders on my G: drive to Share with Everyone, and I've disabled the requirement for a password for sharing (the one user account on my desktop doesn't have a password). On my laptop in the living room, I tried to map a network drive to `\\MyPC` but Windows tells it cannot connect. If I type in `\\MyPC` in the address bar, it shows the Music and Videos folders just as I'd expect it to. Unfortunately I can't post the exact error as I'm not at home right now.

Took me a while to figure out the password-required for sharing issue, is there some other obscure setting for this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot map a network drive to a computer – it must be connected to a specific share; that is, not `\\MyPC` but `\\MyPC\Videos`.

Comment: I see, thanks. Did not know that. I'll mark as Answer when I can.